# How to control youtube iframe player API using Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular, iframe, youtube

[https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/player/](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/player)

Hi there,

I need to change the behavior of the functions provided in demo.js and make database calls to my mongodb instance. I can write APIs to access the mongodb and get information but cannot seem to pass the data back into the demo.js file.

I have linked the YouTube player repository which contains the demo.js file.